# Why does my JSTL if-check doesn't work?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl, conditional-statements

I am trying to create simple application with log in function, using Spring Security. But i can't achieve desired result. 
JSTL tag on my .jsp page doesn't pass test, while scriplet code does which i want to avoid in my application.

My JSP page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Log in page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<c:url value="/login"/>" method="POST">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
</form>

// This block of code is never executed
<c:if test="${error != null}">
    Some test message
</c:if>

// While this one works fine
<%
    if (request.getParameter("error") != null) {
        out.write("error's value isn't null\n");
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter overriden configure method:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.antMatchers("/product")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')");

        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
}
```

Spring MVC Controller's method for mapping "/login" request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model,
                            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error {
        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Username or password is incorrect.");
        }

        return "login";
    }
```

And this is what I get requesting http://localhost/login?error :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wjxX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
```

to

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

As i understood, EL evaluation was deactivated, so i manually activated it.